# How to display a specific value from the array in Jquery / getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Basically I am getting a JSON feed using jquery using:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/1.php?method=getAllUsers&jsoncallback=?")
```

I get the values successfully from the feed stored in an array called `data`

eg.:

```
x => 1
y => 3
z => 5
```

(obviously this is in the json format)

after this script i have the html, and a table

```
<table><tr><td>y</td><td>value of y from the feed</td></tr></table>
```

now how can i get the specific value of `y` into my table? any help would be apreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something that didn't work? Because I would imagine that using `json_object.y` would give you that value.

Comment: please read the question - he knows how to access the object, what he doesn't know is how to insert it into his HTML

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DOM methods to find the appropriate `<td>` element and change its content.

As you're already using jQuery the simplest thing would be to put an `id` on that `<td>`:

```
<td id="foo"> ... </td>
```

and then use this in your script:

```
$('#foo').html(data.y);
```

(i.e. set the inner HTML content of the element with ID `foo` to `data.y`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery template plugin to compile your data with your template, that may be the best way to do this, see more info here

[JQuery Template](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)